# как добавить линию тренда на такой код в питоне

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

```
# NINO
import numpy as np
import xarray as xr
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
noaa_nino3 = pd.read_csv('https://www.cpc.ncep.noaa.gov/data/indices/sstoi.indices',
                      sep=r" ", skipinitialspace=True,
                      parse_dates={'time': ['YR','MON']},
                      index_col='time')['NINO3']
noaa_nino3.head()
noaa_nino3.plot()
plt.grid(axis="y")
plt.grid(axis="x")
plt.show()
#####################################
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: я прикрепил код который из данных noaa строит график изменения аномалии, и мне нужно что бы на графике также была линия тренда, что бы видеть тенденцию графика

Comment: Смотря что вы имеете в виду под трендом. Единую прямую линию для всего графика или какой-то аггрегат, как в уже данном ответе?

Comment: да да, именно единую линию для всего графика

Comment: Ну вот например через `Seaborn` легко сделать: https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/regression.html

Answer (score 1):

```
# NINO
import numpy as np
import xarray as xr
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
noaa_nino3 = pd.read_csv('https://www.cpc.ncep.noaa.gov/data/indices/sstoi.indices',
                      sep=r" ", skipinitialspace=True,
                      parse_dates={'time': ['YR','MON']},
                      index_col='time')['NINO3']
noaa_nino3.head()
noaa_nino3.plot()
plt.grid(axis="y")
plt.grid(axis="x")
noaa_nino3_mavg20 = noaa_nino3.rolling(window=20, center=False).mean() # new
plt.plot(noaa_nino3_mavg20.index, noaa_nino3_mavg20.values) # new
plt.show()
```

Результат

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Пример с использованием `Seaborn`:

```py
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'data': np.random.rand(100) + np.linspace(0, 1, 100)})
df.iloc[10] = 2
df.iloc[80] = 0
sns.regplot(x=df.index, y=df['data'])
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если у вас на графике есть выбросы, то линия тренда может нарисоваться не совсем правильно, тогда рекомендуется использовать параметр `robust`:

```py
sns.regplot(x=df.index, y=df['data'], robust=True)
```

[Больше примеров тут.](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/regression.html)